# AWS System Manager Run Command on EC2 Failes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, amazon-systems-manager

I'm running a fastapi server on ec2 ubuntu. Everything work fine when I ssh in to ec2 and run commands, but I want the server to be running when my local machine is off.
So, I tried AWS System manager's run command. The connection looks fine but when I `cd` to the server code and run `ls` it outputs nothing. Also, when I do `poetry run python main.py` in the server folder, which works totally perfect when I ssh in to the server from my local machine, it says `poetry: not found`.
Why is this happening. And is there another way I can run my server while being able to turn off my local machine.

Comment: Your ec2 machine does not have your local machine code, you need to push your code from local machine to ec2 machine.

Comment: Yes the code is in the ec2 server. I said everything works fine when I "ssh" in to the ec2 from my local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any kind of relation between your machine and your server in the cloud, and your ec2 its still alive and runs your services whenever you want

Comment: But if I run server from my local machine by ssh when I kill my local machine the server also dies.

Comment: Who does die? ec2 server its self or your services inside ec2?

Comment: my service on ec2

Comment: yes, you just need to run it in the background, if you like make service in Linux and run it always